# twisted - transfer data using json

Tags: json, python-2.7, twisted

I need to transfer data (objects) between client and server, and Twisted seems a good way to accomplish this. I've been doing a lot searching but still haven't found any example to understand the basic principle. So any simple code would help.

Thanks!

EDIT

- Both client and server are written in python
- The data may be large, so I need a fast, reliable transmission ( I've taken a look at [producers](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html), is that good?)
- Flask is great, but I am using another framework, so the whole networking thing relies on Twisted.

Comment: "Fast" transmission compared to what?  When would you need slow transmission?  "Reliable" compared to what?  Do you just mean "reliable" in the TCP sense of "ordered"?

Comment: It's hard to say what I need to compare to, but when I say "fast", I mean the latency is acceptable (so it should be CPU efficient and has not too much overhead). And yes, "reliable" refers to TCP (no packet lost expected)

Comment: Acceptable to whom?  For what purpose?  Industrial mechanical control?  In that case I'm afraid Python is unsuitable and you'll need a hard realtime language, and also JSON is not a good choice because you can't decode it in a fixed cycle count.  I'm not trying to be difficult - my point is that these qualifiers are worse than meaningless without more explanation about what you're trying to achieve.  Surely nobody would propose a solution that is slow just for the sake of being slow.

Comment: OK, you can forget about the "fast" requirement (and of course realtime, too), do you have an example of json string transfer with twisted?

Comment: Transferring a JSON string isn't really different than transferring any other kind of string using Twisted.  `json.dumps` / `json.loads` will convert objects to and from JSON pretty straightforwardly.  What have you tried already? What documentation have you found? This question is *really really* vague.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if your question is more about json, python or twisted, but here's an overview, more can follow once the specifics are known.  Perhaps you could add some more info to your question so we can offer more assistance :-)

re Json:  Json is just a string with a defined structure.  If you are working in python and have an object to send as json, then you need to convert the object to a json string by use of

```
import json
json.dumps(objectName)
```

If your client is javascript then instead of json.dumps you might use JSON.stringify(objectname).

If you intend to use javascript for clients then some of the frameworks like jQuery make it very easy.

Pythons json.dumps has a lot of optional arguments, most of which you won't need.  You can see the options at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Python is python, I assume you know how to create and populate objects.  Will your client be python or javascript or something else?  From a javascript client to a python server you would most likely use Ajax to send requests and get responses.

Twisted allows you to easily create a server that will listen on a given port and, when data arrives, an event will occur that supplies the data received.  You can then do whatever you need to with the data.  Just be careful about doing blocking things like database inserts since the server may miss some data or otherwise misbehave if you interrupt it's event loop.  Twisted can be difficult to learn initially, but it is a very powerful and reliable system that is well proven.  One alternative to consider, particularly if your clients are not python, is node.js.  In my opinion, node is a little bit easier to grasp initially and there are thousands of add-on modules that let you do almost anything you'd want.  I use both twisted and node for different things.

<s>Neither node.js nor twisted are software that you can use to just quickly spin up a server or client without some study and experimentation.</s>  To use Twisted or Node.js <s>properly</s> confidently, using all their features and goodness, requires a bit of research and work on your part.

There are excellent frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that can be used to build a server that can react to a number of different Ajax calls from a client - you can have a single server be able to respond to several different kinds of requests instead of having a server for each Ajax type.

Comment: `twistd -n web` is a pretty quick way to spin up a server with Twisted. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a small library that serializes an object with all its children to JSON and also parses it back to a fully working object:

https://github.com/Toubs/PyJSONSerialization/